# Generating random matrix in C but numbers are same position

Tags: c

When I run the code numbers are always the same positions. For example, the output is always:

```
1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 
1 1 0 1 (x=3 y=4)
```

How can I change the locations of these numbers?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int i, j, m, n;

    printf("Matrix'in X eksenini giriniz: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    printf("Matrix'in Y eksenini giriniz: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", rand()%2);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to call `srand` before using `rand`. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once).

Comment: You need to seed the random number generator by calling `srand()`.  One barely adequate possibility is `srand(time(0));` — and including `<time.h>`.  That gives you a different sequence as long as you don't call the program twice in one second, but the output is not very random because the seed is predictable.